# Database mirroring on Rackspace or Xeround

Tags: mirroring

I´m trying to resolve following problem.

I have 2 application servers on Rackspace that are connected to a load balancer. Both servers must have the same applications and share the same data. Basically on each server is a Java EE application that will be writing some data into database. This data will be accessible from outside. Each server must have the same data (so he has to take them from the other servers database and viceversa).

This fact means that I need to have 2 database servers (so that one database server is not so busy if we have big traffic). To have the same data on both database servers, I was thinking of mirroring one to another (Master - Master connection). I found a Xeround database cloud, and I was thinking of creating two database instances there and accesing them from Rackspace. (Server A -> Database server A; Server B -> Database server B). And Database server A <-> Database server B would have Master - Master connection (so both servers will have the same data periodically updated).

Is this a possible and effective solution ? Or is there a better solution?

Comment: Which Database are you using: SQL server, MySQL, Oracle? Also, please edit the tag accordingly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I work for Xeround. With Xeround [cloud database](http://xeround.com) you do not need to mirror your database, you create a single database instance and direct your application servers to work with this instance. Hope this helps!

Avigail

Comment: But if we have big traffic, cant this usage of only one database server instance cause very slow exchange of data between application server and database server? We implemented a load balancer for these two application servers because of low latency from app. servers to end-users. So we thought of setting up as many database instances as we have app. servers

Comment: Our architecture is distributed and already includes built-in replicas. So assuming you're connecting to the DB from apps in the same Rackspace datacenter latency should be low. We automatically scale-out the front ends if you require more throughput- to address the need from the application.

Comment: Okay thank you very much for help. So we dont have to worry about these thing because all these things work automtically. Fine now we can test it. :)

Comment: If Xeround had sql server support, to let me log ship from my production sql server box.... THEN we would be talking! MySQL.... not in use here....